# how to execute a command for multiple occurrance and change the variable from list each time

Tags: tcl

I have a list which contains
   72.xx.xxx.xxx          72.xx.xxx.xxx
(There are some spaces )
I have a variable say var

Now I have to execute a command for $var times and I have to use "72.xx.xxx.xxx" each time.
let us say the command is :
"reset vpn $IP".

I have to execute the above command say two times (stored in variable) and for two IP address stored in list.
Can any one help with TCL code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a homework.  And the task specification lacks some important details.

If you want to iterate over *all* IPs in the list, just do

```
set ips {72.xx.xxx.xxx 72.xx.xxx.xxx}
foreach ip $ips {
  reset vpn $ip
}
```

If you add more values to the `ips` list, the [`foreach`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/foreach.htm) command will iterate more times, over all the remaining elements.

If you want to iterate over, say, first N elemnts, just pick them one by one:

```
set ips {72.xx.xxx.xxx 72.xx.xxx.xxx 72.xx.xxx.xxx 72.xx.xxx.xxx ...}
set ntimes 2
for {set ix 0} {$ix < $ntimes} {incr ix} {
  reset vpn [lindex $ips $ix]
}
```

And so on.

No rocket science. Just read [the tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html), read [the book](http://beedub.com/book) and please try to refrain from such simple questions before you actually tried yourself first.

Comment: You can use `lrange` to pick the list to iterate over, but if you're updating the list during the loop you _must_ use the longer `for` construct; `foreach` fixes the list(s) it iterates over at the point when it starts.